# How to split strings using C# and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, split, .net

I want to split a string like Members in table Set and select the result with other fields as a record.

For example, lets assume the Set has 2 fields `(ID, Members)` and 2 records: `(1, "A, B")` and `(2, "C")`.

Now I need a Linq query to retrieve records as: `(1, A), (1, B), (2,C)`.

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ-to-SQL won't do this, but you can retrieve this data using LINQ-to-SQL and then run straight LINQ against it.

```
List<Set> sets;
using (var context = new MyDataContext())
{
    sets = context.Sets.ToList();
}

var result = sets.SelectMany(s => 
    s.Members.Split(',').Select(m => new { s.ID, m }));
```